# Norm of linear functional

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

For every $ x \in C([a,b])$, we define the functional $F(x) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} {\lambda_{i} x(t_{i})}$ where $\lambda_{i} \in R, i=1,...,n$.

I was wondering if someone can help me to find a sequence of continuous functions $x_{n}$ such that $\frac{|F(x_{n})|}{||x_{n}||_{\infty}} <||F||$ as $n$ goes to $\infty$ ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $|F(x)|\leqslant \sum_{j=1}^n|\lambda_j|\lVert x\rVert_\infty$, hence $\lVert F\rVert\leqslant \sum_{j=1}^n|\lambda_j|$.

There is actually equality. To see that, we can construct a continuous function $x$ such that $x(t) \in [-1,1]$ for each $t\in [a,b]$ and if $i\in\{1,\dots,n\}$, then $x(t_i)=\begin{cases}
1&\mbox{ if }\lambda_i\gt 0;\\
-1&\mbox{ if }\lambda_i\lt 0;\\
0&\mbox { if }\lambda_i=0.
\end{cases}$

Comment: Actually, my purpose is to prove the equality but since the other inequality is not very difficult, I  only asked about the second one. How one can prove the continuity of such a function?

Comment: We can choose $x$ such that its graph is a polygonal path.